# VBA is not creating PivotCache

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro to create a pivot table, but the pivot table is not created, because the pivot cache is not created. I can't seem to figure out why. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong please?

```
Dim LastColumn As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim wsTO As Worksheet, wsEF As Worksheet
Dim wbTO As Workbook
Dim PCache As PivotCache, PTable As PivotTable
'Determine the data range you want to pivot
LastColumn = wsTO.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = wsTO.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set PRange = wsTO.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastColumn)

'Set the pivot cache
Set PCache = wbTO.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=wsEF.Cells(10, 7), _
TableName:="PostOccupationTable")
'Create a blank pivot table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=wsEF.Cells(10, 7), TableName:="PostOccupationTable")
'Insert Row & Column Fields
 With wsEF.PivotTables("PostOccupationTable").PivotFields("IndCategory2")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With wsEF.PivotTables("PostOccupationTable").PivotFields("PostCategory2")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
'Insert data field
wsEF.PivotTables("PostOccupationTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PostOccupationTable").PivotFields("NAME"), "Count of NAME", xlCount
'Set filters
With wsEF.PivotTables("PostOccupationTable").PivotFields("PostCategory2")
    .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
End With
With wsEF.PivotTables("PostOccupationTable").PivotFields("IndCategory2")
    .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
End With
'Apply Style
wsEF.PivotTables("PostOccupationTable").TableStyle2 = _
    "PivotStyleMedium2"
```

Comment: You `Dim wsEF As Worksheet` and then use `TableDestination:=wsEF.Cells(10, 7)` but you never defined a worksheet for `wsEF`. You must do something like `Set wsEF = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")` (same issue for `wsTO` and `wbTO` both are not defined to a worksheet/workbook). • By the way your code should throw an error message. If you have errors and ask a question always tell which line the error is and which message.

Comment: ok, I did that, just forgot to copy that part of the code, that is not the problem.

Comment: We still cannot see that in your question. If we don't have the code you are **actually** using we cannot provide help. The code you have shown won't run at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching on other fora, I have found that the problem is related to the fact that excel doesn't always accept a range that is set (although it should).
I have rewritten the code to encode the range as a STRING, using the R1C1 reference style, which solves my problem. The cache and thus the pivot table is now created. Full working code below.

```
Dim LastColumn As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim wsTO As Worksheet, wsEF As Worksheet
Dim wbTO As Workbook
Dim PCache As PivotCache, PTable As PivotTable
Dim PivotRange As String

Set wbEFiche = Workbooks("ThisWorkbook.xlsm")
Set wsEF = wbEFiche.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsTO = wbTO.Sheets("Sheet2")

LastColumn = wsTO.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = wsTO.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'Due to an excel bug, the range has to be encoded in a string format, using a R1C1 reference style
PivotRange = wsTO.Name & "!" & wsTO.Range(wsTO.Cells(1, 1), wsTO.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1)
'Set the pivot cache
Set PCache = wbTO.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PivotRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=wsEF.Cells(10, 7), _
TableName:="PostOccupationTable")
'Create a blank pivot table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=wsEF.Cells(10, 7), TableName:="PostOccupationTable")
'Insert Row & Column Fields
 With wsEF.PivotTables("PostOccupationTable").PivotFields("IndCategory2")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With wsEF.PivotTables("PostOccupationTable").PivotFields("PostCategory2")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
'Insert data field
wsEF.PivotTables("PostOccupationTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PostOccupationTable").PivotFields("NAME"), "Count of NAME", xlCount
'Set filters
With wsEF.PivotTables("PostOccupationTable").PivotFields("PostCategory2")
    .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
End With
With wsEF.PivotTables("PostOccupationTable").PivotFields("IndCategory2")
    .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
End With
'Apply Style
wsEF.PivotTables("PostOccupationTable").TableStyle2 = _
    "PivotStyleMedium2"
```